# Проблема с авторизацией Uber API android

Tags: java, android, api

```
     config = new SessionConfiguration.Builder()
            .setClientId("CLIENT_ID")
            .setServerToken("TOKEN")
            .setRedirectUri("com.example.asus.uniontaxidouble.uberauth://redirect")
            .setScopes(Arrays.asList(Scope.PROFILE, Scope.RIDE_WIDGETS ))
            .setEnvironment(SessionConfiguration.Environment.SANDBOX)
            .build();

 LoginCallback loginCallback = new LoginCallback() {
@Override
public void onLoginCancel() {
    // User canceled login
}

@Override
public void onLoginError(@NonNull AuthenticationError error) {
    // Error occurred during login
}

@Override
public void onLoginSuccess(@NonNull AccessToken accessToken) {
    // Successful login!  The AccessToken will have already been saved.
}



AccessTokenManager accessTokenManager = new AccessTokenManager(context);
LoginManager loginManager = new LoginManager(accessTokenManager, loginCallback);
loginManager.login(activity);
```

**Но при авторизации выходит ошибка, уже неделю мучаюсь с этой проблемой, гугл не помогает. Помогите пожалуйста**
[image: Скрин файла конфигурации и настройка личного кабинета]
[image: Экран ошибки]

Comment: Вы с OAuth2 до этого работали?..

Comment: в `setRedirectUri` необходимо указывать свой `URI`... например `setRedirectUri("https://konstantin.sherba.ru/uber_auth/")`...

Comment: нет, там предоставляется url в формате applicationId.uberauth://redirect думаю дело в нем, что я делаю не так?)

Comment: вы зарегистрировали данный RedirectUri (`com.example.asus.uniontaxidouble`)  в [панели управления UBER](https://developer.uber.com/dashboard)? Пакет соответствует Вашему applicationId?

Comment: а `redirect` в Uri где потерялся?

Comment: `build.gradle` свой приложите пожалуйста к вопросу

Comment: Да , я зарегистрировал свой URL в  панели управления UBER